# Docusign - Reset authentication failed

Tags: authentication, docusignapi, envelope

I integrate `DocuSign` in my webSite with `API`.

When a recipient failed his authentication, he can't retry signing the same envelope because he has an authentication failed. For my integration I want to reset the authentication status if a recipient failed it like that, he can retry to sign the envelope.

So, I retrieve `RecipientAuthenticationStatus` property and I try to set it to `null` or `empty` object and after update recipients for the envelope. **But there is not any update impacted after this call.**
Can we change the authentication status failed for a recipient like that he will be able to retry signature without of resending the envelope? (Without any impacting for other recipients and continue to work with the same envelope). Thanks for help

Comment: You're doing embedded signing, not embedded sending, right? When you say failed authentication, what kind of authentication are you using? There are many options.

Comment: I'm doing embedded signing and embedded sending. The user in my website can choose either sms code or access code in his profile. So, I need to handle these two types of failure. But now, if I resend the enveloppe that contains two recipients. If one has already signed the document but the other has failed his authentication. When i resend this enveloppe, the recipient who had already signed has to sign again the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you can give a recipient (signer) multiple authentication options for them to try. If they fail one, then they can try another.

This is the "Custom Authentication" option.

But once a signer has failed all of the authentication options provided by the sender, I think that's it. Time for a new envelope (resend the old one as a new envelope).

Perhaps you could edit the envelope to add the signer as another signer for the envelope but you'd need to deal with the tabs too.

Failing authentication is supposed to mean something. [Docs](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-recipient-authentication)

Comment: Ok ok. But now, if I resend the enveloppe that contains two recipients. If one has already signed the document but the other has failed his authentication. When i resend this enveloppe, the recipient who had already signed has to sign again the document? 
I will try your idea that consists to add the signer as another signer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have resended envelope and it's ok, recipients who have already signed the envelope mustn't sign again the envelope. Thanks for your help Larry K.